Spring boot @RequestBody of a Map<String,String>[] reult in a list of empty items
Client side is an angular webApp. I try to send to a spring boot REST API a List of Map<String, String>, but it appears that it is serialized as a List of empty items.
I tried also using an array  Map<String, String>[] and using a Map of Objects.
Here is the POJO definition :
public class ClasseurDTO {

    private Map<String,String>[] ongletGeneralite;
    
    public ClasseurDTO() {
    }

    public Map<String, String>[] getOngletGeneralite() {
        return ongletGeneralite;
    }

    public void setOngletGeneralite(Map<String, String>[] ongletGeneralite) {
        this.ongletGeneralite = ongletGeneralite;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // parse ongletGeneralite object 
        String str = "";
        for (Map<String, String> map : ongletGeneralite) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                str += entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue() + " ,";
            }
        }

        return "ClasseurDTO [ongletGeneralite=" + str + "]";
    }
}

Here is the typescript type def
export type ClasseurDTO = {
     ongletGeneralite : Map<string, string>[]
}

The method definition of the API :
@PostMapping("/public/observations/import-observations")
public ResponseEntity<String> importObservations(@RequestBody ClasseurDTO classeur) {
    observationService.importObservations(classeur);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Importation terminée");
}

Here is the http call
  importClasseur(classeur: ClasseurDTO): Observable<HttpResponse<{}>> {
    console.log("importClasseur" , classeur)
    return this.http
    .post(`${this.resourceUrlPublic}/import-observations`, classeur, { observe: 'response' });
  }

Here is the log on the client side just before calling the API

Here is the payload in the network debug tool

Could someone pinpoint where the issue is ?

You payload itself going empty. Issue is with your client app not server side. Please share relevant code to debug further

I edited to add the http call

I continued to investigate and tried several things.
I just changed the input type as a string[][][] instead of the List of Map, letting all the remaining source code unchanged, and noticed that the nested items weren't empty.
So I ended up expanding definitions and using this in client side :
export class CellDataClasseur {
    cellData : string[] = []
}

export class LigneDataClasseur {
    ligneData : CellDataClasseur [] = [];
}
export class ClasseurDTO  {
     ongletGeneralite: LigneDataClasseur[] = [];

}

And this POJO server side :
public class CellDataClasseur {
private List<String> cellData;

public List<String> getCellData() {
    return cellData;
}

public void setCellData(List<String> cellData) {
    this.cellData = cellData;
}
}

public class LigneDataClasseur {
private List<CellDataClasseur> ligneData;

public List<CellDataClasseur> getLigneData() {
    return ligneData;
}

public void setLigneData(List<CellDataClasseur> ligneData) {
    this.ligneData = ligneData;
}
}

public class ClasseurDTO {
private List<LigneDataClasseur> ongletGeneralite;

public List<LigneDataClasseur> getOngletGeneralite() {
    return ongletGeneralite;
}

public void setOngletGeneralite(List<LigneDataClasseur> ongletGeneralite) {
    this.ongletGeneralite = ongletGeneralite;
}
}

I let the question opened in case someone can explain how serializing Map, if it's possible, or how to improve my solution
